# Is the standalone ecj (Eclipse Java Compiler) package no longer maintained?

Tags: java, eclipse, ecj

We are using `ecj` from `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler` in our project, however it looks like the package is not updated since 07-Oct-2016. Is it no longer maintained?

[image]

Or should I switch to the `ecj` from `org.eclipse.jdt`? Looks like the version number (3.20.0) is older than the former: `4.6.1`?

Comment: What site is that? The official site For Eclipse 2019-12 project downloads is [here](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.14-201912100610/).  This was a new release yesterday and includes a standalone ecj

Comment: Here is the site: https://search.maven.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official coordinates of `ecj` in Maven are indeed: `org.eclipse.jdt:ecj`.

As you can see, this artifact exists in all release versions since `3.12.3` (corresponding to Neon.3).

Artifacts in other groups may have mistakenly used the version number of the Eclipse release, not that of ecj itself, thus appearing to be newer even if they are (a lot) older.

(*When Eclipse SDK was bumped up from 3.x to 4.x this was due to breaking changes in the UI part of the code. ecj, however, remained compatible and thus stayed at 3.x*)

In case of doubt, run the following to see the real version of `ecj`:

```
$ java -jar ecj.jar -version
```

The latest release version will answer

```
Eclipse Compiler for Java(TM) v20191203-2131, 3.20.0, Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2015. All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 0):

That will change with [Eclipse 4.27 (2023-03 release)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.27/jdt.php#ecj-separated-from-core):

> ### ECJ separated from JDT Core
>
> Historically the code for ECJ was always in the same `org.eclipse.jdt.core` project that also contained the code for the Java support in the IDE, just in a different source folder.
>
> The well known standalone ECJ compiler library that could be used outside of Eclipse (for compilation with external tooling) was generated out of this core bundle at build time and was not included in the default SDK (because it contained subset of packages and classes provided by `org.eclipse.jdt.core`).
>
> This lead to few issues, with both Eclipse / standalone use of the ECJ compiler.
>
> - The (non-JDT) code inside Eclipse that required "default" `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` API implementation and had no need for full JDT / workspace support was not able to use `org.eclipse.jdt.core` without pulling in `org.eclipse.core.resources` bundle and so the dependency to the workspace.
> - Another interesting side effect of hosting ECJ code next to IDE code inside same `org.eclipse.jdt.core` bundle was that developers couldn't see if the ECJ code per mistake got some dependency to the IDE.
>
> To resolve these (and other) problems, **the ECJ code is moved from org.eclipse.jdt.core to dedicated `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch` project** and will be deployed as a separated bundle.
>
> The `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch` is now included in SDK as a regular Eclipse bundle and can be compiled / deployed / used separately from `org.eclipse.jdt.core bundle`.
>
> All of ECJ packages are re-exported by `org.eclipse.jdt.core`, therefore from OSGI point of view, all 3rd party code that used some compiler related API from `org.eclipse.jdt.core` doesn't require any change.
> The `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch` bundle itself doesn't have any dependencies and so can be used in Eclipse products that do not use workspace concepts.
>
> However, no change is without side effects.
>
> #### Known problems with the split of the ECJ from core bundle
>
> - As part of the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch` code separation from `org.eclipse.jdt.core`, the two fragments of `org.eclipse.jdt.core` - `org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt` and `org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool` were merged into `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch`.
>   So if some target definition, launch configuration or build file referenced the two fragments, these references can and should be removed now.
> - Another issue might affect standalone (non OSGI based) applications that were using `org.eclipse.jdt.core` as a "simple" Java library (which `jdt.core` never was).
>   So for example code that had `org.eclipse.jdt.core_XYZ.jar` on classpath and tried to call this outside Eclipse:
>
>   ```
>   ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.getJLSLatest());
>   ```
>
>   would fail now with:
>
>   ```
>   NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.ICompilationUnit
>   ```
>
>   because `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser` uses internally ECJ APIs and they are now ... surprise ... moved to `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch` jar.
>   To fix this error, `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch` library should be added to the application classpath.